# How to make JavaFX Applications non-blurry on Retina Display

Tags: scala, javafx-2, javafx, retina-display

A JavaFX application appears blurry on the MacBook Pro Retina screen. Is there a way to display the application sharp? In a blog post/comment was mentioned that this is the case currently: http://fxexperience.com/2012/11/retina-display-macbook-pro/

This is the example fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>


<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <MenuBar>
        <Menu text="File">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Exit"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>
</VBox>
```

Example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import javafx.stage.Stage

object CreateFX extends App {
    override def main(args: Array[String]) = {
      println("CreateFX starting up...")
      Application.launch(classOf[CreateFX], args: _*)
    }
}

class CreateFX extends Application {
    def start(stage: Stage): Unit = {
        println("start "+stage)

        stage.setTitle("CreateFX")

        val root: VBox = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreenVBox.fxml"))//new VBox

        val scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600)
        scene.setFill(Color.GREEN)

        stage.setScene(scene)
        stage.show()
    }
}
```

Outcome: 
[image: Resulting application]

Java Version: `1.7.0_21`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same article in the commentary Richard Blair stated that this was fixed in the latest JavaFX version (available in the EAP of Java 8, downloadable [here](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html))

Comment: I see. So this is not yet implemented in Java 7?

Comment: It's unlikely that JavaFX retina support would ever be backported to Java 7.  All JavaFX support for Java 7 is currently in maintenance mode and new features (such as Retina support) are delivered for Java 8+.

Comment: Is it just me or is this the answer to almost any question about JavaFX recently? I wish they'd release Java 8 already!

Comment: @CraigMcMahon i'd rather have them backport more of the bugfixes / new features to JavaFX 2.2 :/

Comment: Do we know if a fix for this is available in OpenJFX somewhere? I found recently that an IME bug could be resolved by referencing the OpenJFX sources and creating a custom Skin implementation for the text field control.